# Separate pppoe session for each user windows, is it possible?

Tags: networking, operating-systems

There are windows, 3 users work in it at the same time, how to make a separate connection for each user? The problem is that when one user connects, the rest automatically join this network, but need to be separate. How can this be done? Any Windows OS interests.

Comment: With a router that supports VLANs

Comment: Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use a router that connects to a LAN port on the ISP Modem and that allows separate connections by the users. VLANs can do this and is probably the most practical way. Configure the ISP modem (or the router) to make the PPPOE connection. The exact setup depends on your ISP. Then connect the 3 Windows Computers to the router (one computer on each port).

If the business has a setup with 6 IP addresses (common), you could use an IP for each user.

Comment: Ty for the answer. I know how to do this with three computers, I am wondering how to do this on one machine with three users.

Comment: You cannot do 3 connections on one machine for 3 users as the network connection is common to the machine. You need multiple IP addresses for multiple different connection profiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple users signed in to the *same* Windows system (I'm assuming it's Windows Server?), as far as I know you cannot achieve this using ordinary VPN connections – the routing changes are always global for the entire system.

You might need to use the "Always-On VPN" feature (which requires IKEv2) in its User Tunnel mode, but even then it's unclear from documentation whether this system actually supports multiple concurrent tunnels. (And of course it requires having your own server, not a third-party VPN service provider.)